# HTTP address with Javascript inside address

Tags: javascript, http, hyperlink

I'm looking for very specific way to open links or create shortcuts to open links with already loaded Javascript on website.

For example. I have portal to which I have link:

**example.com/text/nu#action:projmgr.text&id123456** but on site there is gear icon which have to be activated and then selected *Export to Excel (Data Only)* which is a JavaScript link like **javascript:text.text.exportToFile('npt.(...)'500','text.text').**

I have like 50 lists to export by clicking on the first link and then navigate through those steps.
Is it possible to create shortcuts to Javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have a look at bookmarklets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

It would be a enormous (XSS/CSRF) security problem if a URL could be constructed which caused a browser to visit a URL and execute arbitrary JavaScript or follow links.

Consider using a tool like Selenium or PhantomJS instead.

Comment: Actually I can use only Internet Explorer because I'm working on Virtual Desktop because of security in client network (intranet only). Thanks for clearing that out. Best Regards

Comment: Selenium is compatible with Internet Explorer.

Comment: yeah, the only one solution was hyperlinks with JavaScript. As i understand Selenium is a plugin to IE. From client side I'm not even able to open any Internet link (intranet only), everything is closed for me so downloading plugin will be impossible for me.